# Esconder modal ao clicar no botão "Fechar" bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html

Bom, eu tenho o seguinte arquivo com uma modal que foi feita por um amigo para mim:

Contudo, quando se clica em Open Small Modal funciona muito bem, mas quando de seguida clico em fechar a modal não fecha novamente, em contra partida se eu clicar fora do fechar, ou seja fora do Modal ela fecha.

Como poderia fazer para que ela fechasse ao clicar no botão fechar e para que não fechasse quando se clicasse fora da modal?

Código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://i.imgur.com/Pr1JDoh.png"/>
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="theme-color" content="‪#3863FF‬">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#subir').click(function(){ 
          $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
      return false;
         });
     });
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <style>
    .modal.modal-wide .modal-dialog {
  width: 20%;
}
.modal-wide .modal-body {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

/* irrelevant styling */
body { text-align: center; }
body p { 
  max-width: 100px; 
  margin: 20px auto; 
}
#tallModal .modal-body p { margin-bottom: 200px }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Small Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-body"><br>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px; margin-top:40px; margin-bottom:40px; data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
          </body>

</html>
```

@EDIT:

Código Atual:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script> $('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', show: false});  </script>

    </head>
        <div class="container">
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Small Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-body"><br>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px; margin-top:40px; margin-bottom:40px;" >Fechar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div
```

>

Obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa fazer assim:

```js
  $('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', show: true});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Small Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-body"><br>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px; margin-top:40px; margin-bottom:40px;" >Fechar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Você esqueceu de `data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"`.

Comment: Já está a funcionar, contudo como bloqueio a parte de fora, para que quando cliquem por fora da modal n fechar?

Comment: Acrescentei o pequeno *script* que impede fechar com o clique fora.

Comment: O script não está a funcionar.

Comment: Você pode executar o código direto aqui pra testar @Gonçalo. Clique no botão "Executar trecho de código" e veja que está funcionando.

Comment: Vou atualizar a pergunta com o meu código, pois o meu quando se clica por fora continua fechando. Para ver se me consegue ajudar a achar o erro.

Comment: Mas eu usei seu código haha. Poste pra eu ver.

Comment: Já postei, não consigo achar o erro, pois de fato o seu está a funcionar aqui no stackoverflow.

Comment: Cara o seu *script* tem que ficar depois do html do modal. Coloca no Rodapé o: <script> $('#myModal').modal({backdrop: 'static', show: false});  </script>

Comment: Consegui!, Muito Obrigado Ricardo!, já agora só uma pergunta extra, como poderia fazer para que não precise clicar no "Open Modal" para abrir a modal, ou seja mal entre no site abre logo a modal...

Comment: Ao invés de false adicione *show: true*. Já alterei meu código aqui.

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Você utilizou corretamente o `data-dismiss="modal"` porém esqueceu de fechar as aspas do style e causou erro de syntax.

Para bloquear o fechamento da modal clicando fora utilize o  `data-backdrop="static"`.

**Exemplo:**

```
<div class="container">

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Small Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-body"><br>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px; margin-top:40px; margin-bottom:40px;" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Esse "  data-backdrop="static" meto no button ou na modal?

Comment: Não está a funcionar.